# Unable to choose a correct combinator for parsing and deal with it in Scala

Tags: xml, parsing, scala, parser-combinators

I have this code which involves scala's `Parsers` class:

```
trait SomeTrait extends SomeTrait2 {
  def myParse = {
    phrase(rep(
            ElemName(Some("http://someUri/"), "someNode1") ~       //compiles well, but fails sometimes at runtime
            ElemName(Some("http://someUri/"), "someNode2") ^^
            {
              case p1 ~ p2 ⇒  //......
            }) ^^
            {
              case p1 ⇒  // ....
            })
  }
}
```

where

```
case class ElemName(namespace: Option[String], name: String) {
   // .....
}
```

Normally, "`someNode1`" and "`someNode2`" both exist in the input soap string (which is not specified here, but it doesn't matter). However, sometimes **either one of them might exist** or even none of them, and in this case it crashes at runtime.

```
<items>
  <subItems>
    <someNode1 val1="123" val2="456" />
    <someNode1 val1="123a" val2="456c" />
    <someNode1 val1="123b" val2="456d" />
    <someNode2 val1="123" val2="456" />
  </subItems>
  <subItems>
    <someNode2 val1="123cd" val2="456de" />
  </subItems>
  <subItems>
  </subItems>
  <subItems>
    <someNode1 val1="777" val2="888" />
  </subItems>
<items>
```

I have to handle that. So I did:

```
trait SomeTrait extends SomeTrait2 {
  def myParse = {
    phrase(rep(
      ElemName(Some("http://someUri/"), "someNode1") |          // should work
      ElemName(Some("http://someUri/"), "someNode2") ^^ 
      {
        case p1 ~ p2 ⇒  //......
      }) ^^
      {
        case p1 ⇒  // ....
      })

      //or, I'm not sure which one to choose
      //ElemName(Some("http://someUri/"), "someNode1") |||      // should work also
      //ElemName(Some("http://someUri/"), "someNode2") ^^ 
  }
}
```

and this should work as I understand. However, at this point it doesn't compile anymore since it says:

```
constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
[error]  found   : SomeTrait.this.~[a,b]
[error]  required: ElemName
[error]           case p1 ~ p2 ⇒ {
[error]                   ^
[error] one error found
```

I believe I must replace case p1 ~ p2 with something else.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that | and ||| both return a single token. Specifically:

`a | b` tries to parse a, returns if it succeeds and trys to parse b if it fails
`a ||| b` tries to parse a and b and uses the result of whichever one parse the most characters. I don't think either of them are what you want. And if they are, you should just use `p1` not `p1 ~ p2`. I think that what you really want is:

```
phrase(rep(
  ElemName(Some("http://someUri/"), "someNode1").? ~
  ElemName(Some("http://someUri/"), "someNode2").? ^^ 
  {
    case Some(p1) ~ Some(p2) ⇒  //......
    case Some(p1) ~ None => //.....
    case None ~ Some(p2) => //.....
  })
```